# value is not set in slider html control

Tags: javascript, html

About Range input type in HTML
When I change value in slider (Range input type) that value in display in textbox 
But when I also same thing in change value in textbox it’s not set that value in slider (Range input type).
Here is code
Function for it:
we also want that when we slide the slider as well as value will change in textbox too 
function :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function updateTextInput(val) {
document.getElementById('textInput').value=val; 
}
function updateTextInput2(val) {
document.getElementById('range1').value = val;
}
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="range1"      onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);"/>
   <input type="text" id="textInput" value="0"      onchange="updateTextInput2(this.value);">
```

Comment: It seems to work, you have to focus out after changing the value

Comment: Can you please tell me how to focus out after changing value because we are using this control for first time

Comment: You can use `onkeyup` instead of `onchange`

Answer (score 0):

Debug the updateTextInput  function to verify the value to set,

or try

document.getElementById('textInput').value = document.getElementById('range1').value;

Comment: where should put this in function updateTextInput or updateTextInput1

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the event where the function is called in the textbox from *onchange* to *oninput*. The *onchange* event only fires after the control loses focus, i.e. when the user clicks on something else. The *oninput* event gets fired every time the user changes the value in the textbox.

Your code should look like this:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="range1" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);" />
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="0" oninput="updateTextInput2(this.value);">
```

Your JavaScript functions work 100% fine.

Here is a working example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/martiensk/pen/zqRNEb/).

Comment: when I input any number in textbox that slider comes in center when I am using oninput

Comment: It definitely works, I have edited my post and added a link to an example. Have a look at it, if you still have a problem please paste your full code.